# Random shapes appearing on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like some help on making shapes randomly appear on my canvas and staying in the position they appear. Currently i have a button which when pressed three shapes appear, but I would like these three shapes to appear continously around the canvas until the button is pressed again.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="example1" width="800" height="600">
    <p class="canvas-no-support">Your Browser Does Not Support HTML5 canvas!</p>
</canvas>

<button onclick="start()">Go!!</button>
```

Script:

```
function start() {
    setInterval(draw, 100);
}

function draw() {
    // get the canvas element using the DOM
    var canvas = document.getElementById('example1');

    // Make sure we don't execute when canvas isn't supported
    if (canvas.getContext) {

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //Red Square

        function dSqu() {
            context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,215,0)"; //Yellow Outline
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
            context.lineWidth = 4; //Stroke Thickness
            context.fillRect(75, 75, 137, 137);
            context.strokeRect(75, 75, 137, 137); //Outline
        }

        function dCir() {
            //Purple Circle
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(380, 137, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(200,80,200)";
            context.fill();
            context.lineWidth = 4; //Stroke Thickness
            context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,215,0)";
            context.stroke();
        }

        function dTri() {
            //Green Triangle
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = "rgb(0,200,0)";
            context.moveTo(100, 100);
            context.lineTo(300, 100);
            context.lineTo(200, 200);
            context.lineTo(100, 100);
            context.fill();
            context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,215,0)";
            context.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        dSqu();
        dCir();
        dTri();

    } else {
        document.write('Your Browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.');
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to make a repeating operation and [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) to get a random number.

For example :

```
var functions = [dSqu, dCir, dTri];
setInterval(function(){
   functions[Math.floor(Math.random()*functions.length)]();
}, 200);
```

This would call every 200 millisecondes one of your three functions (`dSqu`, `dCir` or `dTri`), taken randomly.

In order to have this working, you need to have the functions visible. You may for example change your code to

```
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('example1');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
function dSqu(){    
    ...
}
function dCir(){    
    ...
}
function dTri(){
    ...
}
var functions = [dSqu, dCir, dTri];
setInterval(function(){
   functions[Math.floor(Math.random()*functions.length)]();
}, 200);
</script>
```

Comment: I have used it in the following manner.... function start(){   
   var functions = [dSqu, dCir, dTri];
setInterval(function(){
   functions[Math.floor(Math.random()*functions.length)]();
}, 100);
}

Comment: [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) is better than `setInterval`.

Comment: In your start function, the three drawing functions aren't defined. Move them to the global scope.

Comment: @katspaugh I'll recommend this method the day the big warning in the page you linked to is gone ("This is an experimental technology"). *If* it goes away. It's not even supported in IE9.

Comment: forgive me a global scope in javaScript is defined in the following way? <script>

var dSqu = dSqu();
var dCir = dCir();
var dTri = dTri();

function start(){   
   var functions = [dSqu, dCir, dTri];
 setInterval(function(){functions[Math.floor(Math.random()*functions.length)]();
  }, 200);
 }

Comment: No. `var dSqu = dSqu();` does nothing useful. It would assign to a variable the result of this (still undefined) variable executed. I'd suggest you start with the code I proposed and you progressively, if you want, try to embed some parts in other functions.

Comment: Thanks @dystroy, I have laid the code as you've suggested, and currently the triangle is flickering in the same place, and no random movement.

Answer (score 1):

This code works well for me and should work for you

```
<script>

function drawShapes(l,w,x,y,colourOfLines,colourOfRect){
    var c=document.getElementById("c1");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(x,y,l,w);
    ctx.fillStyle=colourOfRect;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle=colourOfLines;
    ctx.strokeRect(x,y,l,w);
    }
for (i=0;i<=32;i++){
    l=Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1);
    w=Math.floor((Math.random()*200)+1);
    x=Math.floor((Math.random()*800)+1);
    y=Math.floor((Math.random()*800)+1);
    x1=Math.floor((Math.random()*555)+1);
    c2=Math.floor((Math.random()*555)+1);
    c3=Math.floor((Math.random()*555)+1);
    c4=Math.floor((Math.random()*555)+1);
    c5=Math.floor((Math.random()*255)+1);
    c6=Math.floor((Math.random()*223)+1);
    drawShapes(l,w,x,y,"rgb(221,23,263)","rgb(c4,c5,c6)")
    }

</script>
```